# How can I cast SQL DateTime Null to c# 'DateTime?' (Nullable<DateTime>)?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, datetime

When the database value 'CompletionDate' is Null. I get the error: *Specified cast is not valid*.

I thought using 'DateTime?' with the question mark would allow this cast to work.

Any advice?

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id;
    public DateTime? CompletionDate;

    private static Application LoadFromDatabase(int id)
    {
        DataRow dr = null; // Loaded from database

        return new Application()
        {
            Id = (int) dr["ApplicationId"],
            CompletionDate = (DateTime?)dr["CompletionDate"]
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is use the ternary operator for this.  Here is an example:

```
CompletionDate = !dr.IsNull("CompletionDate") ? (DateTime)dr["CompletionDate"] : new DateTime?();
```